# MS Workflow Foundation 4 - Can the workflow model be interigated at runtime, as in to generate a visual representation of it?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

can the workflow model be interigated at runtime.
Reason, to generate a visual web representation of it? For highlighting the current node of the workflow, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check on the activity tree the WorkflowInspectionServices will help you do that.

Comment: Thanx for the tip. Some more info at the following 2 links: Workflow Foundation 4.0 Activity Model (I) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/flow/archive/2010/01/24/lights-camera-activities-windows-workflow-foundation-s-activity-model.aspx
And Activity Tree Inspection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358719.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this link about dynamically changing workflows, which would imply that the workflow can be interrogated at runtime.
http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/08/28/4322.aspx

Comment: The linked article is about WF3 and has no relevance to WF4 whatsoever.

Comment: Good point. However, if it was supported in 3, it is reasonable to expect something similar in 4 as well. :) I'll look into it.

Comment: It would be reasonable. Unfortunately WF4 is a completely new and different code base and schedule triumphed over reason in some cases :-(

Comment: I hear you, but the activity tree should give us what we would require to build a simple representative visual model of the workflow, correct?